# Type conversion in Orientdb

Tags: orientdb, type-conversion

I have a query in Orientdb like this:

```
select out('E_MyEdge').@rid, creationUser from V_MyVertex where out('E_MyEdge').@rid <> creationUser
```

V_MyVertex is a vertex, E_MyEdge is an edge. creationUser is a property of type "LINK" from V_MyVertex, which is an "rid" (something like "#12:4"). The problem is both columns from result are kind of "rid", but the query returns also the rows which have the same value (for example   #12:117 | #12:117), and I don't know how to exclude them from the result.

Comment: Is your goal to select all outgoing vertices from a vertex,which is not connected at the vertex linked in creationUser ?

Comment: The original select is without this "where" clause, and I have to add this clause to exclude some records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
select out('E_MyEdge').@rid, creationUser from V_MyVertex where out('E_MyEdge').@rid NOT IN creationUser
```

Hope it helps

Comment: In the first case (my version of query), I have 221 records. In the second version, I have 938 records. And also, in this case, most of the records from the second column are empty.

Comment: I can't understand what you want to achieve, could you do me a small example?

Comment: Initially, I extracted some clauses from the query. Now, I tried to add in the original query the clause exactly like you wrote, and it seems it works fine. My clause with "[...] <> creationDate" confused me when I tested the results.